# Running Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

I have successfully installed right version of Chrome from here:

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

However, when I am trying to open it via the terminal I get the following error:

labsPC:~$ google-chrome-stable
[26712:26712:0916/155253:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(264)] Failed to create /home/invictuslabs/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: File exists
[26712:26712:0916/155253:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1155)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: This probably belongs on Superuser as stated above. Maybe try deleting the lock file? '/home/invictuslabs/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock'